# Set Inclusion Involving Convergence in Measure in Finite Measure Space

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, geometric-measure-theory

Consider a measure space $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ with $\mu(X)<\infty$. Let $f_n$ be sequence of measurable functions such that $f_n \to f$ in measure. That is, for any $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $N$ such that for $n \geq N$,
$$
 \mu(\{x \in X: |f_n(x) -f(x)| \geq \varepsilon\}) < \varepsilon.
$$
In addition, since $\mu(X)<\infty$, we also have for any measurable functions $g$, there exists a constant $M<\infty$ such that
$$
\mu(\{x \in X: |g(x)| \geq M\}) < \varepsilon.
$$
and below is my main question:

> I was wondering for $n \geq N$, do I have the following set inclusion:
>   $$
> \left\{x: |g(x) (f_n(x) - f(x))| \geq \varepsilon  \right\} \subset_? \left\{x: |g (x)| \geq M\right\} \cup \left\{x: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{ M} \right\}
> $$
>   I intended to believe the inclusion above holds but not very clear on it and  would appreciate if someone could guide me on how to prove this or point out that I am doing something wrong.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $|g(x)| < M$ and $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \frac\epsilon M$ then $|g(x) (f_n(x) - f(x))| < \epsilon$. Now take the complementary set

Comment: I see it now, thanks a lot!